# Why is this custom view with multiple GroupBys and one OrderBy not working?

Tags: list-view, caml-query

1. First Group By is not working (however the second file subcategory Group By works)
2. The OrderBy is not working
3. Show all items without folder is not working

Any ideas??

```
private static void CustomView(SPWeb web, SPList spList)
{
    SPViewCollection oViewCollection = spList.Views;
    string strViewName = "Custom_View";
    System.Collections.Specialized.StringCollection viewFields = new System.Collections.Specialized.StringCollection();
    viewFields.Add("File Type");
    viewFields.Add("Name");
    viewFields.Add("File Date");
    viewFields.Add("File Number");           
    //string strQuery = "<OrderBy><FieldRef Name=\"LinkFilenameNoMenu\" /></OrderBy>";  //works

    string strQuery = "<GroupBy Collapse=\"TRUE\" GroupLimit=\"100\">" +
                        "<FieldRef Name=\"File Category\"/>" +
                        "<FieldRef Name=\"File Subcategory\"/>" +
                        "</GroupBy>" +
                        "<OrderBy>" +
                        "<FieldRef Name=\"LinkFileName\"/>" +
                        "</OrderBy>";


    oViewCollection.Add(strViewName, viewFields, strQuery, 100, true, true);    
    spList.DefaultView.Update();
    spList.Update();

    SPView view = spList.Views["Front_Page"];
    view.Scope = SPViewScope.Recursive;
    spList.Update();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Problem Solved.

1. Used LinkFilenameNoMenu for order by and it works.
2. Used File_x0020_Category instead of File Category in group by and the group by working.
3. Added view.update() to make recursive working.

Thanks